# Terminal: run source ~/.bash_profile every time start new terminal

Tags: terminal, mac, bash

I installed some command line programs (e.g. `rbenv`), but every time I open a new Terminal tab, it looks like the environment gets reset. I need to source my *.bash_profile* manually:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

I followed some tutorials and put this code in my *.bash_profile*, but it doesn't work:

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ] && [ -f $HOME/.bashrc ];then
    source $HOME/.bashrc
fi
```

This doesn't happen on my old Mac, and I don't know how to configure this.

Comment: What do you mean by the code "doesn't work"? - How doesn't it work? - Do you actually have a .bashrc file?

Comment: Have you tried closing Terminal.app and starting it over?

Comment: yes. i have created bashrc file. (and run source ~/.bash_profile)

Comment: @jksoegaard yes. I have restarted terminal app.

Comment: And what is your problem exactly? - That the code inside .bash_profile is not run? - or that the code inside your .bashrc file is not run? Are you sure you named it ".bashrc" and not "bashrc" (note the leading dot)

Comment: If `.bash_profile` doesn't get sourced automatically on startup, changing its content (as you describe in the question) won't make it get sourced. What is in your `.bashrc`, in your `.bash_profile`, in your `.profile`?

Answer (score 32):

If you are using [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh), 
the default one that will be loaded automatically is `~/.zshrc`. All you need to do is adding the following at the end of `~/.zshrc`:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_profile ]; then
  . ~/.bash_profile
fi
```

Answer (score 7):

`.bashrc` will be loaded per default, so if you have all your stuff in `.bash_profile` ensure it will be loaded, so you have to add to your `.bashrc`:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_profile ]; then
  . ~/.bash_profile
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

You can edit your environment in `~/.zprofile` instead of `~/.bash_profile`. Then, reopen a terminal.

Comment: On MacOS Monterey this was the only answer that worked for me (by running .bashrc inside .zprofile). .bashrc, .bash_profile, and .zshrc are not run on their own.

Comment: works for me fine with .zprofile