# Create extra dock item that runs a bash script

Tags: terminal, bash, dock

I currently have the Terminal in my dock. I'd like to have another Terminal shortcut in the dock but with this one it will run a bash script which will do some stuff specific to that shortcut.

No, I cannot use .bash_profile since the original Terminal short cut will source that too.

This is pretty trivial to do in Windows, is it trivial on a Mac also?

Comment: Can you clarify "which will do some stuff specific to that shortcut"?

Comment: @benwiggy Run a bash script of my liking.

Comment: Are you just trying to just execute a _shell script_ that runs to its completion and the _session_ terminates, or  are you trying to open a new instance of **Terminal** that stays open, is interactive and has a different environment then **Terminal** normally has?  Which is it?

Comment: @user3439894 Stays open and is interactive!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have files in the Dock, but they have to be the other side of the 'dividing line' from apps.

So a shell script file, with suffix `.command`, or `.tool`, could be in the Dock and would launch on a click.

There are other places to have scripts readily accessible in the Mac workspace, of course, such as the Scripts menulet.

Comment: What I want basically is to open a terminal window that has sourced a bunch of files. Basically .bash_profile but specific for this terminal shell session.

Comment: Ok thanks, it's working now, made a command script, added to the dock, ran my stuff and then sourced .bash_profile then ran bash. Working as intended, ta.

Comment: Instead of sourcing .bash_profile I added https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/357362/123669 to the .bashrc file.